# Looping through a list of dicts in python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, iteration

can someone help me learn how to `loop` through the items listed below?
I am getting a `dict` inside a `list`. 
Trying to learn how to get each item by itself

This is the results that I get when I connect:

```
[
    {
  "Index": "NASDAQ",
  "ExtHrsChange": "-0.22",
  "LastTradePrice": "972.92",
  "LastTradeWithCurrency": "972.92",
 }
]
```

Current code:

```
for line in quotes: 
    (key, value) = line.split() 
    if "LastTradePrice" in key: 
        print key
```

Comment: this is my loop:                                                                                         
for line in quotes:
    (key, value) = line.split()
    if "LastTradePrice" in key:
        print key

Comment: So did you figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks to be a string in json format except for an extra comma at the end of the dictionary list (maybe you manually typed this?).  Use the json module to parse it and then iterate over the list of dictionaries:

```
raw_data = '''\
[
    {
  "Index": "NASDAQ",
  "ExtHrsChange": "-0.22",
  "LastTradePrice": "972.92",
  "LastTradeWithCurrency": "972.92"
 }
]'''

import json
data = json.loads(raw_data)

for item in data:
    for key,value in item.items():
        print(key,value)
```

> ```
> Index NASDAQ
> ExtHrsChange -0.22
> LastTradeWithCurrency 972.92
> LastTradePrice 972.92
> ```

Comment: thank you very much for the help. it worked for me once i added the josn.loads and looped through data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop to take every dictionary in the list and then use the builtin `items()` method to split the keys and values from the dictionary:

```
l = [
 {
    "Index": "NASDAQ",
    "ExtHrsChange": "-0.22",
    "LastTradePrice": "972.92",
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "972.92",
 }
]

for i in l:
    if "LastTradePrice" in i:
        for a, b in i.items():
            print a, b
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help, it is working for me now. This is exactly what I wanted to learn how to do.

Comment: @JZi  Please accept this answer so that other users know your post has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Python2 try `iteritems()`:

```
dict_list = [
    {
    "Index": "NASDAQ",
    "ExtHrsChange": "-0.22",
    "LastTradePrice": "972.92",
    "LastTradeWithCurrency": "972.92"
    }
]

for entry in dict_list:
    for key, value in entry.iteritems():
        print key, value
```